# What needs to be installed, to use ST_ClusterDBSCAN?

Tags: postgis, clustering

I have working PostgreSQL 9.5.3 with PostGIS.
I have sucessfully created table and column with geom data type.
I am able to execute geometry queries, namley ST_Transform without problem.

```
# SELECT ST_Transform(location_geom, 26986) FROM table;
                    st_transform                    
----------------------------------------------------
 01010000206A6900003CB104EFAB3D6241733751CA4EDF5941
(1 row)
```

However, when trying to use ST_ClusterDBSCAN it says, it does not know function like this.

```
SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(location_geom, eps := 0,5, minpoints := 2) FROM table;
ERROR:  function st_clusterdbscan(geometry, eps => numeric, minpoints => integer) does not exist
```

Same result when I append "OVER ()" just after ST_ClusterDBSCAN(...), although I do not know what it does, but I have seen it in documentation.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html

What needs to be installed, to use ST_ClusterDBSCAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need PostGIS 2.3 which was released on 9/26/2016.

Check

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

If it says less than 2.3, you are out of luck.

Comment: I should add, if you are on windows, experimental binaries are available here: http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/   I don't think any distros have released binaries for 2.3, so you'd have to compile yourself if you are on another platform.

Comment: OP said he was using 9.5.3, but maybe that is incorrect.

Comment: 9.5.3 is my version of postgresql, however postgis version is 2.2.1 and indeed, documentation says it required 2.3.0, I didn't pay attention.
Actually, I do not need ST_ClusterDBSCAN, but any clustering algorithm - are You able to suggest any that exists in postgis 2.2.1?

Comment: PostGIS 2.2 has `ST_ClusterWithin` (equivalent to DBSCAN with minPoints = 1) and `ST_ClusterIntersecting` (equivalent to DBSCAN with minPoints = 1 and eps = 0)

Answer (score 0):

You need postgis >=2.3 which is out just now: https://t.co/5wyd4nVer3